# use async operation inside cycle for with timeout

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, async-await

Problem: I have a list of users to delete. Not only the user himself is deleted, but also a significant amount of data associated with him. Some tables that are involved in deleting user information contain millions of records.
All internal processes are started asynchronously when deleted. And if, when deleting one user, there are no problems, and all processes in the background are successful (that is, the client does not expect a response), then if you run several of them, this takes all the server resources, which naturally negatively affects the work of the site as long as it goes removal.

```
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const user = users[i];
    await this.removeInstance(user, removedBy);
}
```

**this.removeInstance** contains many other asynchronous operations.

What I want: start an asynchronous operation **this.removeInstance** at 3 minute intervals.
The speed of data deletion is not important to me, but according to my observations 1-2 minutes is exactly enough to "completely finish" with one user.

***Note:*** this.removeInstance return removed user, but I cannot use this, since a dozen processes are already running in the background to clear his information.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper function that delays an async task completion to a minimum:

```
const wait = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const delayCompletion = minTime => task =>
  Promise.allSettled([task(), wait(minTime)])
    .then(([result]) => result.status === "fulfilled"  
      ? result.value 
      : Promise.reject(result.reason)
    );
```

Example:

```js
const wait = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const delayCompletion = minTime => task =>
  Promise.allSettled([task(), wait(minTime)])
    .then(([result]) => result.status === "fulfilled"  
      ? result.value 
      : Promise.reject(result.reason)
    );
      

//showcase:

async function main() {
  console.log("-- start loop --");
  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(`start iteration ${i}`);
    
    const delayAtLeastTwoSeconds = delayCompletion(2000);
    const oneSecondtask = () => wait(1000);
    
    await delayAtLeastTwoSeconds(oneSecondtask);
    
    console.log(`finish iteration ${i}`);
  }
  console.log("-- finish loop --");
}

main();
```

[`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) waits until all promises are no longer pending. We give it one asynchronous task an it adds another for a minimum delay, so if `task` finishes early, then it still has to wait until the delay timer is finished. Conversely, if the delay timer finishes *first* but `task` has not, then that will still be awaited.

`Promise.allSettled` resolves to an array of promises where each has a status `"fulfilled"` or `"rejected"`. We are only interested in the first item of the array because it's `task` - the second one is the delay. We just return its value if it was successful *or* reject with the original rejection reason, if it wasn't. That way `delayCompletion` still preserves the same semantics as the original promise and any code that consumed the original promise can transparently consume the promise from `delayCompletion`.

In some respects, this is the opposite of [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) which instead resolves to the promise that resolves first. Instead we wait for the *last* one but we do have a fixed return value.

With this helper function, your code can be transformed like this:

```
const safeDelay = delayCompletion(3 * 60 * 1000); //3 minutes

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const user = users[i];
    await safeDelay(() => this.removeInstance(user, removedBy));
}
```

Comment: Interesting but... UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Promise.allSettled is not a function. Node version?

Comment: @RomanKovalevsky [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled#browser_compatibility), this will work with Node 12.9.0 and above. EDIT: it seems [there is an npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.allsettled) that can be used for older environments.

Comment: Thank you. My version "@types/node": "^10.7.1".  I think your solution is the best, but unfortunately I cannot apply it. And I'm not ready to upgrade Node yet :)

Comment: @RomanKovalevsky I've edited my comment. There is a package you can import to use `allSettled` with if `Promise.allSettled` is not available.

Comment: Yes, it does work. As I understand it, I can now set a delay of 1 minute and not worry if suddenly the operation and all its child operations are not completed within the allotted time?

Comment: @RomanKovalevsky if you set a delay of one minute then, that's the minimum completion time. So, if `this.removeInstance(user, removedBy)` takes 40 seconds, the next iteration will still wait another 20 seconds. If the `this.removeInstance(user, removedBy)` takes 2 minutes, then the next iteration will start immediately after it finishes.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution is the most reliable and fully corresponds to the task that was before me. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother you, but a solution has been found.
[How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop/44476626)

Final:

```
public async removeBatchUsers(usersEmailsList: string[], removedBy: IIdentity) {
    const users: UserSchema[] = await User.find({userEmail: {$in: usersEmailsList}});

    const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

    async function load (that) {
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            const user = users[i];
            await that.removeInstance(user, removedBy);
            await timer(10000);
        }
    }

    load(this);
}
```

The solution above using Promise.allSettled is the most correct and safest. Tested it, in my case I had to additionally install the "promise.allsettled" library (23Kb)

Comment: naturally, the timer should be set less, it was just necessary to make sure that they would not be executed at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can fake a sleep function and use it

```js
function sleep(time = 0){
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve()
    },time)
  })
}

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const user = users[i];
    await this.removeInstance(user, removedBy);
    await sleep(1000*60*3)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I posted this answer below, which I found at the link. Thank you for your concern and for your time, I note that your answer also works. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too worried about about how long the whole process takes you can use a for..of loop with `await` to run `this.removeInstance` in series over the array:

```js
for (let user of users) {
  await this.removeInstance(user)
}
```

This will wait for each user to be removed before starting the next - you could then return a http 202 to the client to indicate the message is received and is being processed, perhaps also implementing a polling endpoint to check in on the status of the work.

Comment: OP *is* worried how long it would take. Or rather, how *short* it would take and wants to impose a minimum delay between iterations.

Comment: This will start a lot of nested asynchronous operations running concurrently, I wrote about this question

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question - I took 'The speed of data deletion is not important to me' to mean that the process could take a while provided it didn't eat all of the resources of the server (i.e. kicking off millions of concurrent javascript operations). I think there's a more general point to be made here about architecting your application - If a large amount of background work is harming your webserver's performance you may wish to split that out into a seperate service that can be scaled independently.

Comment: Yes, in the future I planned so, since all accompanying operations when deleting a user are clearly separated and independent, and therefore their execution can be processed separately.